# Why bracket expressions [\w] and [\d] behave differently in GNU sed

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to know why using bracket expressions `[\w]` and `[\d]` in GNU `sed` produces different results:

```bash
$ echo '\weds4'|sed -E 's/[\w]/_/g'
__eds4
$ echo '\weds4'|sed -E 's/[\d]/_/g'
\we_s4
$ echo '\weds4'|sed -E 's/[\s]/_/g'
_wed_4
```

I expected that `echo '\weds4'|sed -E 's/[\d]/_/g'` would produce `_we_s4` and not `\we_s4`

[Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) described that it should match both `\` and `d`, like I'm expecting.

> So in POSIX, the regular expression `[\d]` matches a `\` or a `d`.

Why is it happening?

Demo [here](https://ideone.com/n1xFuZ).

Side note: using BRE instead of ERE doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try `[\\d]` instead?

Comment: Interestingly both `'s/\d/_/g'` and `'s/d/_/g'` result in `\we_s4`, so apparently `\d` is an escape sequence resulting in literal `d`.

Comment: @matt, it produces expected result. But why do I need second slash?

Comment: Because `\d` is a meaningful unit.

Comment: Try  `sed --posix`. The `--posix` option disables GNU extensions, which are on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html :

> Regex syntax clashes (problems with backslashes)
>
> ....
>
> In addition, this version of sed supports several escape characters (some of which are multi-character) to insert non-printable
> characters in scripts (\a, \c, \d, \o, \r, \t, \v, \x). These can
> cause similar problems with scripts written for other seds.

And

> 5.8 Escape Sequences - specifying special characters
>
> [...]
>
> \dxxx
>
> Produces or matches a character whose decimal ASCII value is xxx.

> Why is it happening?

When writing `\d` and there is nothing after it, the https://github.com/mirror/sed/blob/master/sed/compile.c#L1345 case matches and executes https://github.com/mirror/sed/blob/master/sed/compile.c#L1356 `convert_number()` which in case the buffer is empty just assigns `*result = *buf` the character to the result value https://github.com/mirror/sed/blob/master/sed/compile.c#L275 instead of converting the digits after `d`.

This will happen to all the cases in the switch, so `\d` `\x` `\o` with nothing behind will match `d` `x` and `o`. I would count `/\d/` as undefined behavior in GNU sed - `\d` has to be followed by 3 decimals. I would say GNU sed documentation does not specify what should happen on `\d` or `\x` or `\c` or `\o` not followed by digits or followed by invalid characters.

> why do I need second slash?

In POSIX sed all https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html I think all three of your commands are invalid / undefined behavior. Sed does not specify what should happen on `\d` `\s` or `\w`, these are invalid escape sequences, so *you can't expect* them to work. Your commands are invalid. If you want to match `\` you have to escape it `\\`, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tagtcjh_2 .

But it would be nicer to get an error messages from GNU sed like in the case of `\c`.